is C is a linear binary code with check matrix H?
$C$ is a linear binary code with check matrix
$$H =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Assume that you receive the word $1111010100$. Determine the number of words i C and what has been sent, if it is possible (by correcting at most one error). If it is not possible, explain why.
I assumed the answer to the first question was the null space which if I not mistaken is given by the non pivot elements so the last 6 columns so shouldn't the number of codes be 6 since only 6 code give us the 0 vector?
In the solution they multiplied the code word with and got a vector similar as the 5th coloumn in check matrix. They concluded that it was the 5th position in the code word that was the mistake and fixed it. So if I understand correctly. When multiplying a code word with check matrix we will get back the 0 vector in which case the word was correct but if we do end up getting a wrong code word, in order for us to detect it the result vector needs to represent a column and it is the position of that column that we also flip in the code word.

There is a tag coding-theory which is far more appropriate for this question than any of tags that the OP has chosen.
